# Cordova plugin objective C, FMDatabase tableExists argument runs with error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, sdk, cordova-plugins

I have an objective C SDK for push notifications and I am trying to build a framework of that sdk which can be added to a cordova app as a plug in. At some point the sdk creates a database and initializes it with code:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)createDBIfNeeded
{
    NSArray *libraryDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *libraryDirectory = libraryDirectories[0];
    NSString *dbPath = [libraryDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:DB_NAME];
    _db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath];
    [_db setShouldCacheStatements:YES];
    
    if ([_db open] == NO) {
        WLLOG(@"Failed to open database");
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)initDBIfNeeded
{
    if ([_db tableExists:@"events"] == YES && [_db tableExists:@"netstats"] == YES) {
        if ([_db columnExists:@"priority" inTableWithName:@"events"] == NO) {
            [_db executeUpdate:@"ALTER TABLE events ADD COLUMN priority INTEGER"];
            WL_FMDBLogError
        }
        
        [_db executeUpdate:@"VACUUM"];
        WL_FMDBLogError
        
        return;
    }
    
    if ([_db tableExists:@"events"] == NO) {
        [_db executeUpdate:@"CREATE TABLE events (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE, type VARCHAR(255), time VARCHAR(255), data BLOB, priority INTEGER)"];
        WL_FMDBLogError
    } else if ([_db columnExists:@"priority" inTableWithName:@"events"] == NO) {
        [_db executeUpdate:@"ALTER TABLE events ADD COLUMN priority INTEGER"];
        WL_FMDBLogError
    }
    
    if ([_db tableExists:@"netstats"] == NO) {
        [_db executeUpdate:@"CREATE TABLE netstats (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE, wifi INTEGER, wwan INTEGER, overall INTEGER, wifistart_timestamp INTEGER, wifiend_timestamp INTEGER, wifi_totaltime INTEGER, wifi_dirty INTEGER, wwanstart_timestamp INTEGER, wwanend_timestamp INTEGER, wwan_totaltime INTEGER, wwan_dirty INTEGER)"];
        [_db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO netstats (_id, wifi, wwan, overall, wifi_totaltime, wifi_dirty, wwan_totaltime, wwan_dirty) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", @0, @0, @0, @0, @0, @0, @0];
        WL_FMDBLogError
    }
    
    if ([_db tableExists:@"pois"] == NO) {
        [_db executeUpdate:@"CREATE TABLE pois (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE, lat NUMERIC, lon NUMERIC, radius NUMERIC)"];
    }
    
    [_db makeFunctionNamed:@"DISTANCE" maximumArguments:4 withBlock:^(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv) {
        distanceFunc(context, argc, argv);
    }];
    
    /*
     * Enable custom settings for the database, to improve
     * both behaviour and performance.
     * http://sqlite.org/pragma.html
     */
    [_db executeUpdate:@"PRAGMA auto_vacuum = FULL"];
    WL_FMDBLogError
    [_db executeUpdate:@"PRAGMA synchronous = NORMAL"];
    WL_FMDBLogError
}
```

But when the second one is executed at the very first line I get the error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FMDatabase tableExists:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28295caa0'

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yawn ... this is pretty boring ... that exception is very common. You have a class property ```_db``` that, in that line, you message with ```tableExists:``` and a parameter. The exception message tells you that the message does not exist. Either that variable ```_db``` is not what you think it is or you must check the manual, maybe it should be ```tableExist:``` in stead.

Comment: Hmmm ... not so boring ... I checked the docs and it does mention this message but if I check the source ```https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/blob/master/src/fmdb/FMDatabase.m``` it is missing. Maybe contact the developers? The docs state this function is there and as you used it but the source says otherwise.

Comment: Ok, I checked, that ```tableExists``` message is defined as an extension in ```FMDatabaseAdditions.h``` so be sure to include that file for it to work.

Comment: Hello and thank you for you answers. I have added FMDatabaseAdditions.h as an import but the error still occurs. I assume the thing is that I create the _db as 
_db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath]; and it is a FMDatabase object. How i can include FMDatabaseAddition in this initialiation? I am newbie in objc so sorry if i am asking too obvious or wrong things

Comment: I was wondering the same - that maybe _db is not the correct type, but the error makes it clear ```-[FMDatabase tableExists:]``` it is looking for ```tableExists``` on an ```FMDatabase``` instance. If you link the framework correctly and have the correct header then it should just work. If you don't have the correct header it will anyhow not compile, but yours only give the error at runtime. So I think you had the correct header all along, but the framework is lacking that ...Additions file somehow. Just double check how you link to the framework. And no sweat!! Of course you can ask!